# Surface curves equidistant from a simple closed geodesic

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, gt.geometric-topology, curves-and-surfaces

Let $S \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ be a surface embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$,
let's say (to keep it simple) of genus zero.
Let $\gamma$ be a simple, closed, oriented geodesic on $S$.
Because $\gamma$ is oriented, it partitions $S$ into two "halves," $S^+$ and $S^-$.
I am interested in learning properties of the curves that are equidistant from $\gamma$.

Define
$$\gamma^+(\delta) = \{ x \in S^+ \;|\; d(x, \gamma) = \delta \} \;,$$
where $d(x,A)$ is the length of the shortest path on $S$ from $x$ to any point in set $A$.

> **Q1**. Does $\gamma^+(\delta)$ have a name in the literature? Has it been studied?
>
> **Q2**. Under what conditions is $\gamma^+(\delta)$ a geodesic?
>   Presumably rather stringent conditions on $S$.
>
> **Q3**. Under what conditions is $\gamma^+(\delta)$ a simple, closed curve?
>   It might partition into several disconnected components. But perhaps for convex $S$,
>   it is always a simple, closed curve?
>
> **Q4**. Under what conditions could $\gamma^+(\delta)$ be a single point?
>   [Revised to reflect Will Jagy's comment.]
>   (Analogous to the north pole with respect to the equator on a (geometric) sphere.)

Thanks for pointers and help!

---

(Image below suggestive only!)

 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
[image]

Comment: similar to Morse functions, really, and some similar to the cut locus of a point. From an ellipsoid, note that the farthest point (Q4) need not be the same distance from all points of $\gamma,$ although perhaps from two points, otherwise a small movement could take it a hair farther. In general, though,  thinking of hydra heads, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lernaean_Hydra#Heracles_and_the_hydra_in_art

Comment: Alright, one approach with a reference, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut_locus_%28Riemannian_manifold%29#Cut_locus_of_a_subset

Comment: @WillJagy: I am familiar with the cut locus, and although it is certainly lurking here, I do not see a direct connection...

Comment: Right. for Q2, cannot imagine all geodesics unless it is a cylinder over a plane curve.

Comment: You get geodesics for small $\delta$ if the Gaussian curvature is $0$ around $\gamma$. For example, take a tetrahedron with a closed geodesic separating two vertices from the other two. If you want a smooth example, you can smooth the tetrahedron keeping the Gaussian curvature $0$ around the geodesic.

Comment: I think these are sometimes called wave fronts, but sometimes families of equidistants. Imagine that light is emitted simultaneously everywhere along $\gamma$. $\gamma^+(\delta)$ shows the points being illuminated on one side at time $\delta$. This should be a smooth Lagrangian curve until you hit a center of curvature. Arnold said a few times that Cayley investigated these for a triaxial ellipsoid but I haven't found the original yet.

Answer (score 2):

To address question 2, consider perpendicular geodesics connecting $\gamma$ with $\gamma^+(\delta)$. These must be perpendicular with $\gamma^+(\delta)$, too, or else moving slightly in one direction or the other will decrease the distance below $\delta$. Consider the quadrilateral formed by a small piece of $\gamma$, perpendicular geodesics, and a piece of $\gamma^+(\delta)$. The Gauss Bonnet theorem implies that the Gaussian curvature of the interior equals the curvature of the piece of $\gamma^+(\delta)$. If the piece of $\gamma^+(\delta)$ is a geodesic its curvature is $0$, so the total Gaussian curvature in the quadrilateral must be $0$.

The Gaussian curvature doesn't have to be identically $0$ between $\gamma$ and $\gamma^+(\delta)$. For example, you can revolve $y=2+\sin x$ about the $x$-axis and there are parallel geodesics where $x$ is a multiple of $\pi$.

---

(Image added by J.O'Rourke.)
 
 
 
 
[image: ZareSin]

---

Along any geodesic perpendicular to $\gamma$ at $v$ we can construct a function of the Gaussian curvature at distance $d$. Here is a construction that shows the function can change with $v$, unlike the surfaces of revolution: Choose a cylinder $\mathbb{R} \times C$ where $C$ is some plane curve. Choose a smooth function $f$, let $S$ be the surface of points $(x,y,z)$ which are of distance $f(x)$ away from the cylinder. If $f$ has a critical point at $x_0$ then the points of $S$ where $x=x_0$ form a geodesic. We can choose $C$ so that it has flat parts and curved parts, and then the Gaussian curvature does not depend only on $x$ because it is $0$ parallel to the flat parts of $C$.

Comment: I like your $2+\sin x$ example! I took the liberty of adding an image of it to your answer.

Comment: Oops, I stated the locations of the critical points of $2+\cos x$, of course.